# Why is the method for lowest base class is called instead of the top?

Tags: java

I have the code like

```
for(Object obj : list)
    func(obj);

void func(Object o){}
void func(Derived d){}
```

In the case when `obj` is `Derived`, `func(Object)` is called instead of `func(Derived)`. Can anybody tell me how to make `func(Derived)` to be called? Thanks

Comment: Java has compile time binding. The only way to make `func(Derived)` be called to is call the method with a variable that as a _compile time_ type of `Derived`.

Comment: Brace yourselves. Answers using `instanceof` are coming.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sadly, sometimes `instanceof` or `getClass` checks are unavoidable. Have you seen the code for `Arrays.deepToString()`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I know that, but you can also avoid id by using a proper design.

Answer (score 1):

For method arguments, the overloading chosen depends on the compile time type of the object (in this case `Object`).

One solution would be to make `func` an instance method, and override it in `Derived`.

Then you could do

```
for (Base base : list)
    base.func();
```

If you can't do it this way (e.g. because these are not your classes), you would have to use an `instanceof` check

```
for (Object o : list)
    if (o instanceof Derived)
        func((Derived) o);
    else
        func(o);
```

The first approach is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Check if object is Derived and than cast him.
Something like

```
for(Object obj : list){
    if(obj instanceof Derived){
        func((Derived) obj);
    } else {
        func(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't say it was nice thing but it can be done in that way.

Comment: I fixed my wrong answer. "Even better" part was regarding my first answer that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution is

```
for (Object obj: list) {
  if (obj instanceof Derived) {
     func((Derived) obj);
  } else {
      func(obj);
  }
}
```

But this kind of using `instanceof` is usually a code smell and your code probably needs a refactor for using polymorphism. I mean creating an `Ancestor` class with a `func()` method, and extending `Derived` from ancestor, then using `Ancestor` as the loop variable type: `for (Ancestor obj: list) obj.func();` but probably you will need to do further improvements.